# Are gemstones part of [stones] or [jewelry], or should they have their own tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

'*Stones*' can include anything from [river rocks](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/8134/glue-river-rock-to-canvas) to [rubies](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/6000/polishing-a-scratched-ruby).
The latter linked question includes both [stones](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stones) and [jewelry](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewelry) tags, but does not mention anything about the intended use of the stone, so the [jewelry](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewelry) tag seems inappropriate.

The description for [jewelry](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewelry) includes "*the selection of materials*", but that is logically in relation to the creation or reparation of jewelry.

- I think [jewelry](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewelry) should not include gemstones, but should [stones](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stones)?
- *Or* should we have a dedicated [gem-stones](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gem-stones) tag?

Comment: Can you clarify why gemstones should have a separate tag from stones?  Yeah, [stones] covers a range of kinds of stones.  Why wouldn't there be a similar argument for separate tagging for large stones vs. tiny stones, or some other distinction?  i.e., what characteristics of gemstones would provide a tag-related benefit beyond what's provided by the question title and context from other tags?  It seems like there would be potential for a [gemstones] tag to become decoration on a lot of questions for which the distinction isn't germane to the question.  (cont'd)

Comment: [jewelry] wouldn't be relevant to the ruby question if it concerned a loose stone, but the author's usage implies the ruby is in a jewelry setting, which clarifies in the tags that it's a precious stone.  If it was a loose stone, the question wouldn't be harmed by removal of [jewelry] from the tags, since ruby is in the title.

Comment: @fixer1234 I can't really, but the use seems unintuitive, hence the question. Good point, and rather obvious. There is also the [lapidary] tag, but it's more about manipulating (gem)stones than the material itself.